# How to exit java method

Tags: java, class, methods, logic

Sorry for the poor title, i didn't know a better paraphrase..

Sooo i am currently writing a Grocery List program and i am stuck on my addItemsToList method. Basically i want it to have to 'exit' points. One of which will bring you back to the main menu of the application and one of which will bring you back to the context menu of that addItemsToList method.
Unfortunately i am completely stuck.

Here is my code for the method:

```
 private static void addItemsToList(){
        System.out.println("To which category do you want to add? ");
        categoryInstructions();
        int choice2 = scan.nextInt();

        if(choice2 == 5){ // i am "getting out" here just fine
            interact(); // this is the method that instructs everything to happen in the main method
        }else {
            System.out.println("What do you want to add? Type 'exit' for menu");
                i = scan.next(); // this is where the second "exit" point is supposed to be if someone types "exit"

                if (i.compareTo(exit) != 0) {                                         
                        System.out.println("Please enter the quantity ");
                        int quant = scan.nextInt();

                        if (choice2 == 1) {
                            GrocerieList.foodstuffsList.add(i);
                            GrocerieList.foodstuffsAmount.add(quant);
                        } else if (choice2 == 2) {
                            GrocerieList.hygeneList.add(i);
                            GrocerieList.hygeneAmount.add(quant);
                        } else if (choice2 == 3) {
                            GrocerieList.drinkList.add(i);
                            GrocerieList.drinkAmount.add(quant);
                        } else if (choice2 == 4) {
                            GrocerieList.otherList.add(i);
                            GrocerieList.otherAmount.add(quant);
                        }
                    } else {
                        addItemsToList();
                }
        }
    }
```

Just for a better understanding here is categoryInstructions():

```
public static void categoryInstructions(){
        System.out.println("Press");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(1)" + "\t--\t" + "for foodstuffs");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(2)" + "\t--\t" + "for hygene");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(3)" + "\t--\t" + "for drinks");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(4)" + "\t--\t" + "for others");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t\t" + "(5)" + "\t--\t" + "to get back main menu");
    }
```

Now whats happening is that i can exit addItemsToList perfectly fine if `choice2 == 5` but i cannot seem to find the logical solution fo exiting if i is equal to "exit". I got it to work quick and dirty with the application first asking for the quantity and then exiting but that isn't quite what i want.

Since i am (obviously) a beginner any other comments on my style or else would also be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: TL;DR `return;`

Comment: `return` will exit the current method.  Although in your case, I'd change the `if(choice2 == 5)` to `if(choice2 != 5)` and use it to fall through to the next logic flow, otherwise just let the code run to the end of the method and it will return automatically to the caller

Comment: What if you add `if(i.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){   interact(); }` at the second exit point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch case for this purpose, a flag to know when to execute an elegant exit and a while loop to help you stay in the menu until a user provides the correct input.

For instance:

```java
public class Controller {

    private GroceriesController groceriesController;
    private boolean isRunning; // our flag that will help us to quit the menu

    public Controller(GroceriesController groceriesController) {
        this.groceriesController = groceriesController;
    }

    public void run() {
        isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning) {
            clearScreen();
            displayLogo();
            displayMainMenu();
            handleMainMenu(); // method that will do all the job;
        }
    }

    private void handleMainMenu() {
        int userChoice = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (userChoice) {
            case 1:
                groceriesController.handleGroceriesMenu();
                break;
            case 2:
                returnItems();
                break;
            case 0:
                isRunning = false; // exit from the menu
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;
        }

    }

    private void displayMainMenu() {
        System.out.println("\n Grocery store:\n"
                + "[1] Buy stuff\n"
                + "[2] Return stuff\n"
                + "[0] Leave store");
    }
}
```

```java
public class GroceriesController {

    private boolean isRunning; // same strategy as before

    public void handleGroceriesMenu() {
        isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning) {
            clearScreen();
            displayLogo();
            displayMenu();
            handleMenu();
        }
    }

    private void handleMenu() {
        int userChoice = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (userChoice) {
            case 1:
                addItemToCart(item);
                System.out.println("The item: " + item + "has been added.");
                break;
            case 2:
                removeItemFromCart(item);
                System.out.println("The item: " + item + "has been removed.");
                break;
            case 0:
                isRunning = false; // exit from the menu
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;
        }

    }

    private void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("\n Select:\n"
                + "[1] Buy item\n"
                + "[2] Put back\n"
                + "[0] Leave");
    }

}
```

In this way, you can have multiple menus that are calling each other and at the end, the program finishes on its own, without wild return; or System.exit(0);

Edit: Added one more class for better insight.